# ASP.NET Datalist image not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I am using a Datalist to display images in a folder. The code is below:

```
 <div>
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <img src = "<%# Container.DataItem %>" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</div>
```

code behind:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("sony"));

        List<string> aList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var rec in list)
        {
            aList.Add( rec);
        }
        DataList1.DataSource = aList;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
```

Its not displaying the images. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("sony"));

        var aList = from fileName in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("sony"))
                    select string.Format("/sony/{0}", Path.GetFileName(fileName));

        DataList1.DataSource = aList;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```